# Css animation from left to right, then disappear, then right to left. and so on

Tags: css, animation, infinite

I want the animation of Blue line from left to right. then it disappear  and then Orange line from right to left and so on.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/anilchauhan999/8zw59v4j/3/

Please help. Below is the code:

```css
/* ================================ */

.c-logo-box{
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 220px;
   min-height: 60px;
}

.border-bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.b-bar {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: loading 3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: loading 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
    from {left: 0; width: 0; background-color: #f5a622;}
    33.3333% {left: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #002255}

  36%{left: 0; width: 100%;background-color: transparent}

    to  {left: 0;z-index:100; background-color: #002255}
    40%{left:0;background-color: #f5a622}

}
```

```html
 <div class="c-logo-box">                               
   <div class="border-bar ">
       <div class="b-bar "></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `Here is the link:` Where ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anilchauhan999/8zw59v4j/3/

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @Anuresh But i do not want this way. Orange  needs to be start from the right to left.

Comment: `I want the animation of Blue line from left to right. then it disappear and then Orange line from right to left and so on.` ...?

Comment: Thanks i need like this: https://jsfiddle.net/anilchauhan999/f5cxkjst/

Comment: The fiddle has nothing bro

Comment: See this bro: https://jsfiddle.net/anilchauhan999/f5cxkjst/8/  Your code helps

Comment: Ohh ok you want to happen in alternative way

Answer (score 0):

Your `@keyframes`  is bit  complicated. I modified it.

```css
.c-logo-box{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 220px;
 min-height: 60px;
}

.border-bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.b-bar {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: loading 4s linear infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes loading {
    0% {left: 0; width: 0; background-color: #002255;}
   25% {left: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #002255}
   50% {left: 0; width: 0; background-color: #002255}
   51% {left: 0; width: 0; background-color: #f5a622}
   75% {left: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #f5a622}
   100% {left: 0; width: 0; background-color: #f5a622}
}
```

```html
<div class="c-logo-box">                               
   <div class="border-bar ">
       <div class="b-bar "></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```